# Embedding a google map directly from a search term?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Basically I want to embed a map for some terms I have on my site (e.g. "New York") but I don't want to have to manually enter the lat/long coordinates for all these terms. These terms are anyway common/standard enough that Google Map's search essentially always gets it right on the first try, anyway.

Ideally I would just have a little bit of javascript e.g.

```
generateMap("New York");
```

and that would give me the iframe for an embedded google map for the search term "New York".

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll probably need to get a developer key:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

You can fake it by hacking together an iframe for embedding, but that's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. If you just want a static map picture, simply use a url like this will get you what you want:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false

You can see that you can use address like "Brooklyn Bridge, New York" in the "center" parameter directly. For more information please refer to http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fully functional google map, it's a little bit more complicated, basically what you should do is first use what is called "Geocoding Service"(which is a part of google map javascript api v3: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html) to search for the place and get its lag and lng, and then redirect your google map object to center that lag and lng.

You can refer to the source code of this example here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

It contains all the parts that you need, just put them together :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function generateMap(term) {
    var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?=q=".encodeURIComponent(term)."&output=embed&t=m&z=7";
    var iframe = document.getElementById("mapframe");
    iframe.style.display = '';
    iframe.src = url;
}

...

<iframe src="about:blank" width="400" height="300" id="mapframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```